# Cryptanalysis and Copying encrypted volumes

Tags: cryptanalysis, truecrypt

I just recently concerned myself with cryptography due to Snowden's revelations and there are a few things I cannot really wrap my head around but maybe you can help me with that. I am not a mathematican or a programmer and most of the stuff I know about cryptography comes straigt from The Imitation Game, so pleas excuse my ignorance.

First off: Isn't encryption of data completely pointless if the attacker knows what he is looking for? In the movie, Turing encrypted the German codes because he knew how their weather broadcast started every morning. So, if an attacker knows the exact specifics of a file that is likely tucked away in an encrypted container, couldn't he just modify portions of the file to match the unencrypted file to find out the encryption key? If for example a whistleblower gets hold of a set of documents and his employer wants to proof it but only finds an encrypted disc at his workplace. Would it be easy for this employer to decrypt the encrypted data if he had a cleartext copy of the files he is looking for?

And my second burning question: Truecrypt's documentation says that one shouldn't copy an existing volume because working with two copies of the same container "may aid cryptanalysis". Why exactly is that? As far as I understand those two containers would share a master key but how does that aid cryptanalysis? Let's bring up a few situations here: Copying a halfway full container and working on the data of each individually, adding the same or different data to both containers of cloning an empty container and filling it with completely different data. How does any of that enable cryptanalysis?

Comment: 1) modern encryption aims to be immune to known- or even chosen-plaintext attacks. So as long as the crypto is unbroken, known plaintext doesn't matter. 2) truecrypt leaks which 16 byte blocks are identical if you have two containers using the same key.

Comment: Copying the container then modifying one will also leak which blocks were changed. So for example, say I make a copy, then open one of the containers and modify a text file and save it. The attacker now knows which block of ciphertext corresponds to the part of the text file I changed.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Technically it only leaks that information if you have two volumes with the same _header_. If the key is the same but the volumes do not have the same header, then the master key will be different (since it's generated randomly). Of course it will be an issue where snapshots of an encrypted volume are taken over time...

Comment: @forest It leaks it if the AES-XTS key is the same. Not sure which other key you're talking about.

Comment: @CodesInChaos You're right. You said "under the same key". I was just clarifying that it's the master AES-XTS key specifically, not the key derived from the passphrase used to encrypt the master key in the header.